# CategoryAxis - trim strings while keeping ToolTip data with full information

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

In a categorical axis, I have labels for each datum.
The strings are sometimes too long so they overlap with other strings.
There are other elements in oxyplot that can be clipped, e.g. axisTitle, Title, etc.
I would like to clip the axis labels depending on the available space between labels.

[image: too long labels]

This is somehow what I would like to achieve:

`LabelFormatter = a => a.Length > 10 ? a.Substring(0,9) : a`

But LabelFormatter only works for numbers, not strings.

Do you have an approach I could do this so labels are trimmed in the axis, but they still appear complete in the tracker tooltip?

If you wanted to replicate the problem I have, you can:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Load oxyplot.WPF.sln (previously downloaded from github, master branch)
3. Locate Examples \ Example Browser \ CategoryAxisExamples.cs
4. Modify line 34 and replace "A" with "Very long item A", etc.
5. You can now run the Example Browser application and find the example at Category Axis -> ItemsSource - string[] example

```
public static PlotModel ItemsSourceStrings()
        {
            var model = new PlotModel { Title = "CategoryAxis with string[] as ItemsSource" };
            model.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis
            {
                StringFormat = "Very long item {0}",
                ItemsSource = new[] { "A", "B", "C" }
            });
            var linearAxis = new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left };
            model.Axes.Add(linearAxis);
            return model;
        }
```

Comment: it looks like you have already created a sample application that has the problem you are running into. If you included that code, it could make it easier for anyone answering this question to give a clear answer with code.

Comment: ok. I'll do that. It was so simple I thought it was not necessary, but I'll add the code. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get your concept working for the `LabelFormatter` with this code. The number passed into the label formatter is the category index.

```cs
var categoryAxis = new CategoryAxis
{
    StringFormat = "Very long item {0}",
    ItemsSource = new[] { "A", "B", "C" }
};
categoryAxis.LabelFormatter = categoryIndex =>
{
    var actualLabel = categoryAxis.ActualLabels[(int)categoryIndex];
    return actualLabel.Length > 10 ? $"{actualLabel.Substring(0, 9)}...{actualLabel.Last()}" : actualLabel;
};
```

But unfortunately, it looks like the label formatter is incorporated into the text that is used for the tracker text

[image: Screenshot of category axes with edited labels]

If you are OK with extra lines in your labels, you could have a label formatter that adds lines at the end of words depending on the current length of the line. Example code shown below

```cs
var categoryAxis = new CategoryAxis
{
    StringFormat = "Very long item {0}",
    ItemsSource = new[] { "A", "B", "C" }
};
categoryAxis.LabelFormatter = categoryIndex =>
{
    var actualLabel = categoryAxis.ActualLabels[(int)categoryIndex];
    var spaceMatches = Regex.Matches(actualLabel, " ");
    var currentLineStartIndex = 0;
    var formattedLabel = actualLabel;
    foreach(Match space in spaceMatches)
    {
        //you can change the length of the current line allowed before inserting a new line.
        if (space.Index - currentLineStartIndex > 5)
        {
            //start counting the length of the next line starting from the current new line character
            currentLineStartIndex = space.Index;
            //replace the space with a new line character
            formattedLabel = formattedLabel.Remove(space.Index, 1);
            formattedLabel = formattedLabel.Insert(space.Index, "\n");
        }
    }
    return formattedLabel;
};
```

[image: Screenshot of categories edited by adding new lines]

Comment: This is the best approach by now! Currently, I ask the user to rename their categories. This solution would not fit my use case: sometimes, there is a difference in the middle of the string and the rest is the same. If the user could find the difference in the tracker, then it would be perfect! (as it happens with the legends, but not categories).